# what does the select @p1 do in the prepared statement

Tags: sql-server

I have an ms sql trace that shows the following...  what does the select @P1 mean or do?

The Trace shows this

```
declare @P1 intCHAR(10)set @P1=29CHAR(10)

exec sp_prepexecrpc @P1 output, N'gsp_DeleteAccessForAreaGroupByCardholder', 0, 1117687CHAR(10)

select @P1
```

why does it end the event with a select @p1 if it is not doing anything with it?  Several of the events in the sql profiler end in select @p1  or select @p1, @P3, @P4  what is it doing with these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It selects the result from the executed procedure that is sent to the variable, `@P1`, after it is output by its execution.

Comment: what does it do with this value?  this is the last thing in the sql profiler trace.

Comment: `@` variables are temporary and are only used inside the scope they are defined. They are destroyed after use.